# Rails: create multiple objects from one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create multiple objects at once from the same form like this:

```
<div class="container">
 <%= form_tag store_opening_hours_create_path do %>
  <% @opening_hour.each do |hour| %>
  <%= fields_for 'opening_hour = []', hour do |p|%>


  <div class="row">
   <table class="table">
     <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Select a day</th>
       <th>Opens at</th>
       <th>Closes at</th>
     </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>
       <%= p.select :day, [['Monday', 1], ['Tuesday', 2], ['Wednesday', 3],
                             ['Thursday', 4], ['Friday', 5], ['Saturday', 6],['Sunday', 7]], {}, class: "form-control" %>
    </td>

    <td>
      <%= p.select :opens, [['12:00AM', 12], ['13:00PM', 13], ['14:00PM', 14], ['15:00PM', 15], ['16:00PM', 16], ['17:00PM', 17],
                               ['18:00PM', 18], ['19:00PM', 19], ['20:00PM', 20], ['21:00PM', 21], ['22:00PM', 22], ['23:00PM', 23], ['24:00PM', 24],
                               ['01:00AM', 1], ['02:00AM', 2], ['03:00AM', 3], ['04:00AM', 4], ['05:00AM', 5], ['06:00AM', 6], ['07:00AM', 7],
                               ['08:00AM', 8], ['09:00AM', 9], ['10:00AM', 10], ['11:00AM', 11], ['00:00', 0]],
                      {}, class: "form-control" %>

    </td>

    <td>
      <%= p.select :closes, [['12:00AM', 12], ['13:00PM', 13], ['14:00PM', 14], ['15:00PM', 15], ['16:00PM', 16], ['17:00PM', 17],
                                ['18:00PM', 18], ['19:00PM', 19], ['20:00PM', 20], ['21:00PM', 21], ['22:00PM', 22], ['23:00PM', 23], ['24:00PM', 24],
                                ['01:00AM', 1], ['02:00AM', 2], ['03:00AM', 3], ['04:00AM', 4], ['05:00AM', 5], ['06:00AM', 6], ['07:00AM', 7],
                                ['08:00AM', 8], ['09:00AM', 9], ['10:00AM', 10], ['11:00AM', 11], ['00:00', 0]],
                      {}, class: "form-control" %>

    </td>

  </tr>

    <%= p.hidden_field :store_id, value: current_store.id %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>


  <%= submit_tag 'Submit, %>
  <% end %>

 </div>
```

and this what  have inside the controller:

```
 def new
   @opening_hour = []
    7.times do
     @opening_hour << OpeningHour.new
    end
    render :template => "stores/opening_hours/new"
 end

 def create
   params["opening_hour"].each do |hour|
     if hour["day"] != "" || hour["closes"] != "" || hour["opens"] != ""
       OpeningHour.create(opening_hour_params(hour))
      redirect_to(root_path)
   return
     end
   end
end

 def opening_hour_params(my_params)
   my_params.permit(:store_id, :day, :closes, :opens, :valid_from, :valid_through)
 end
```

But when I hit submit I get the following error:

> NoMethodError in OpeningHoursController#create undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass

and this is what  i get inside the rails console:

```
Started POST "/store/opening_hours/create" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-02-23 12:04:07 +0200
Processing by OpeningHoursController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"pQP2xegYmfllUQUpHsWzqy7sEanpMA5cV5Kaiye1s7ogunQ2Et3oKKZnKr7VAsebpp6bxQuDbH07eCJHp4bSdQ==", "opening_hour = "=>[{"day"=>"1", "opens"=>"12", "closes"=>"12", "store_id"=>"1"}, {"day"=>"1", "opens"=>"12", "closes"=>"12", "store_id"=>"1"}, {"day"=>"1", "opens"=>"12", "closes"=>"12", "store_id"=>"1"}, {"day"=>"1", "opens"=>"12", "closes"=>"12", "store_id"=>"1"}, {"day"=>"1", "opens"=>"12", "closes"=>"12", "store_id"=>"1"}, {"day"=>"1", "opens"=>"12", "closes"=>"12", "store_id"=>"1"}, {"day"=>"1", "opens"=>"12", "closes"=>"12", "store_id"=>"1"}], "commit"=>"Submit"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
NoMethodError (undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/opening_hours_controller.rb:18:in 'create'
```

After debugging a little bit inside the create method where the error is happening, I found out that the params["opening_hour"] returns nil and thats why it returns this error.
Any ideas why this is happening and how I can make this work?

**Update 1**

```
Started POST "/store/opening_hours/create" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-02-23 13:22:19 +0200
Processing by OpeningHoursController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"rvNr5bq7DmZtpiMPaE6qYMN2dE7+qarFI2c2e8kedYIrSukWQH5/t66QDJijid5QSwT+IhwayORPjY63SS0UTQ==", "opening_hour = "=>[{"day"=>"1", "opens"=>"12", "closes"=>"12", "store_id"=>"1"}, {"day"=>"1", "opens"=>"12", "closes"=>"12", "store_id"=>"1"}, {"day"=>"1", "opens"=>"12", "closes"=>"12", "store_id"=>"1"}, {"day"=>"1", "opens"=>"12", "closes"=>"12", "store_id"=>"1"}, {"day"=>"1", "opens"=>"12", "closes"=>"12", "store_id"=>"1"}, {"day"=>"1", "opens"=>"12", "closes"=>"12", "store_id"=>"1"}, {"day"=>"1", "opens"=>"12", "closes"=>"12", "store_id"=>"1"}], "commit"=>"Update Account"}
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  Store Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "stores".* FROM "stores" WHERE "stores"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  OpeningHour Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "opening_hours" WHERE "opening_hours"."opens" = $1 AND "opening_hours"."store_id" = $2 AND "opening_hours"."day" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["opens", "12:00:00"], ["store_id", 1], ["day", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  OpeningHour Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "opening_hours" WHERE "opening_hours"."closes" = $1 AND "opening_hours"."store_id" = $2 AND "opening_hours"."day" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["closes", "12:00:00"], ["store_id", 1], ["day", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
```

**Update 2**

```
Processing by OpeningHoursController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"rvNr5bq7DmZtpiMPaE6qYMN2dE7+qarFI2c2e8kedYIrSukWQH5/t66QDJijid5QSwT+IhwayORPjY63SS0UTQ==", "opening_hour = "=>[{"day"=>"1", "opens"=>"8", "closes"=>"17", "store_id"=>"1"}, {"day"=>"2", "opens"=>"8", "closes"=>"17", "store_id"=>"1"}, {"day"=>"3", "opens"=>"8", "closes"=>"17", "store_id"=>"1"}, {"day"=>"4", "opens"=>"8", "closes"=>"17", "store_id"=>"1"}, {"day"=>"5", "opens"=>"8", "closes"=>"17", "store_id"=>"1"}, {"day"=>"6", "opens"=>"0", "closes"=>"0", "store_id"=>"1"}, {"day"=>"7", "opens"=>"0", "closes"=>"0", "store_id"=>"1"}], "commit"=>"Update Account"}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Store Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "stores".* FROM "stores" WHERE "stores"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  OpeningHour Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "opening_hours" WHERE "opening_hours"."opens" = $1 AND "opening_hours"."store_id" = $2 AND "opening_hours"."day" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["opens", "08:00:00"], ["store_id", 1], ["day", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  OpeningHour Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "opening_hours" WHERE "opening_hours"."closes" = $1 AND "opening_hours"."store_id" = $2 AND "opening_hours"."day" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["closes", "17:00:00"], ["store_id", 1], ["day", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (6.5ms)  INSERT INTO "opening_hours" ("store_id", "day", "closes", "opens", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["store_id", 1], ["day", 1], ["closes", "17:00:00"], ["opens", "08:00:00"], ["created_at", "2018-02-23 11:30:04.441164"], ["updated_at", "2018-02-23 11:30:04.441164"]]
   (0.8ms)  COMMIT
```

**Update 3**

opening_hour.rb

```
class OpeningHour < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :store

  validates_presence_of :day, :closes, :opens, :store_id
  validates_inclusion_of :day, :in => 1..7
  validate :opens_before_closes
  validate :valid_from_before_valid_through

 # sample validation for better user feedback
 validates_uniqueness_of :opens, scope: [:store_id, :day]
 validates_uniqueness_of :closes, scope: [:store_id, :day]

 protected
  def opens_before_closes
    errors.add(:closes, I18n.t('errors.opens_before_closes')) if opens && closes && opens >= closes
  end

  def valid_from_before_valid_through
    errors.add(:valid_through, I18n.t('errors.valid_from_before_valid_through')) if valid_from && valid_through && valid_from >= valid_through
  end
```

end

Comment: according to your console params you receive params in `"opening_hour = " =>` not in `"opening_hour" =>` you need to fix this first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply@Pardeep Saini... the error doesn't show up now. But it doesn't create the objects, I'm guessing that it has something to do with  controller method `def opening_hour_params(my_params)'  and that the name of the prams now is `opening_hour =`... any ideas?

Comment: can you show me what you receive as params in create method.

Comment: Yes of course! please check out my question, I have update it! sorry for the format though, I cant get it to show better!

Comment: you record is created and rollback i.e  `OpeningHour Exists (0.4ms)  and (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK` because you are trying to save the identical records. All records in opening_hour array are identical.

Comment: yes you are right!... now it gets created but it only creates one object in my db table and not all seven. please check my question again I have updated it with what it returns now in the console.

Comment: can you post your `open_hours` model.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165716/discussion-between-pardeep-saini-and-theopap).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to save identical records . You need to add validation on frontend for validation of identical records.